# UIDesign for SplitViewController in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

Im my app, i'm using split view controller for the first time. Am converting my iPhone app to universal app. My question is, how should i design the UI for the detail view controller so that it accommodates in the smaller area of the split view controller? That is, my detail view controller .xib file is in normal size landscape mode and when i design UI(insert textfields, labels, etc), they get overlapped. Any hint regarding UI Design for detail view controller?

Comment: UISplitViewController can not support to iPhone/iTouch its only for iPad. You have to think different in this case. I recommend you use UINavigationController.

Comment: @iAmbitious: yeah friend.. Thats right.. My question is, how should be the UIDesign of detail view controller? The UIView of detail page is normal landscape mode. How to design UI such that it fits in the second half of the splitviewcontroller?

Comment: your left side view of UISplitController should be Root of NavigationController and suppose contain an list of element, When you select any option from list you have to navigate page for detail information to next page. That means your detail page must be next page.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally is the splitview master view displayed in a navigation view controller on the iphone. If the user selects any details to diaplay, thé phone display another view. This designpattern is very common and straight foreward.

Create a new project in XCode. Select a master detail template and make sure you use universal for the targets. Explore the new project.

Comment: yeah friend.. Thats right.. My question is, how should be the UIDesign of detail view controller(iPad)? The UIView of detail page is normal landscape mode. How to design UI such that it fits in the second half of the splitviewcontroller?